remix-run: application crashes on unhandled promise rejection in deferred data #9340
I just can't figure it out. When I throw error at the deferred data application crashes with below error.
If I simply return an error Response or catch the promise, then the @remix-run/react/Await element won't understand there is an error.
I'm not sure using process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => -1); in entry.server is a good practice.
Any ideas? Appreciate the help.
npmPackages:
 @remix-run/css-bundle: ^2.9.1 => 2.9.1 
 @remix-run/dev: ^2.9.1 => 2.9.1 
 @remix-run/express: ^2.9.1 => 2.9.1 
 @remix-run/node: ^2.9.1 => 2.9.1 
 @remix-run/react: ^2.9.1 => 2.9.1 
 @remix-run/serve: ^2.9.1 => 2.9.1 
 vite: ^5.2.10 => 5.2.10

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "#<Response>".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}

Actual code:
export async function getFilesByParent(request: Request, params: Params) {
  try {
    const db = await tenantDb({ request, permissions: [UserPermissions.GetFiles] });

    const { parentId, parentType } = parentSchema.parse(params);
    const id = await http.parser.id(parentId); //  Not catching this causes unhandled promise rejection. If we catch this, it won't send error signal to `@remix-run/react/Await` element.

    return await db.query.files
      .findMany({ where: and(eq(files.parentId, id), eq(files.parentType, parentType)) })
      .execute();
  } catch (err) {
    throw jsonErrorResponse(err);
  }
}

export async function parseId(value: string | undefined) {
  return await idSchema.parseAsync(value).catch(() => {
    throw http.err.NotAcceptable('Invalid id!');
  });
}

export async function loader({ request, params }: LoaderFunctionArgs) {
  const files = getFilesByParent(request, {
    parentType: 'customers',
    parentId: params.id,
  });
  //  awaited promise should be the last one to get the full benefit of streaming
  const customer = await getCustomer(request, params);

  return defer({ customer, files });
}


One problem I can see is that you are not sending any Promise with this statement:
return defer({ customer, files });

Both customer & files are awaited and represents actual returned values rather than a Promise. This is not what you want when you are using defer().
